# How to simulate stock prices with stochastic time change subordinated arithmetic Brownian Motion?

Tags: programming, finance

the idea is to simulate price returns thus to be normally distributed i 'am trying to use subordinated arithmetic brownian motion subordinated to time activity (volume)
 stock prices are following GBM then you can say
$$
dS_t=μS_tdt+σS_tdW_t
$$
where the time considered is not the calendar time but activity time (Ané & Geman 2000). I faced problems while implementing it in matlab so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you say what these problems were that you faced in Matlab? Can you post your Matlab code here?

Answer (score 3):

Here it is. Returns here are normally distributed by construction.
It doesn't involve time scale, you can use time, volume, or any other "activity".

```
>> sigma = 0.001;
>> mu = 0;
>> returns = mu + sigma * randn(1000,1);
>> price = cumprod(1 + returns);
>> plot(price)
```

[image]